# Swift 2.2: Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: ios, swift, segmentation-fault

I am getting a segfault: 11 after updating to the latest version of Xcode (7.3). The code that is triggering this is:

```
private func makeScreenshots(points points_I: [[CGPoint]], frames frames_I: [[CGRect]], scale:CGFloat, completion: (screenshots: [[UIImage]]) -> Void) {

        var counter: Int = 0

        // use didSet as a responder to the completion handler,instead of a loop, ensuring nice sequential execution
        var images: [[UIImage]] = [] {
            didSet {
                if counter < points_I.count {
                    internalScreenshotRow()
                } else {
                    completion(screenshots: images)
                }
            }
        }

        // same code is used twice -> nested function
        func internalScreenshotRow() {
            makeScreenshotRow(points: points_I[counter], frames: frames_I[counter], scale: scale) { (screenshot) -> Void in
                counter += 1
                images.append(screenshot)
            }
        }

        internalScreenshotRow() // start first run
    }

private func makeScreenshotRow(points points_I: [CGPoint], frames frames_I: [CGRect], scale:CGFloat, completion: (screenshots: [UIImage]) -> Void) {

        var counter: Int = 0

        // use didSet as a responder to the completion handler,instead of a loop, ensuring nice sequential execution
        var images: [UIImage] = [] {
            didSet {
                if counter < points_I.count {
                    internalTakeScreenshotAtPoint()
                } else {
                    completion(screenshots: images)
                }
            }
        }

        // same code is used twice -> nested function
        func internalTakeScreenshotAtPoint() {
            takeScreenshotAtPoint(point: points_I[counter], scale: scale) { (screenshot) -> Void in
                counter += 1
                images.append(screenshot)
            }
        }

        internalTakeScreenshotAtPoint() // start first run
    }
```

The error being thrown by compiler is:

```
1.  While emitting SIL for 'makeScreenshots' at /ScrollViewImager.swift:115:13
2.  While emitting SIL for 'internalScreenshotRow' at /ScrollViewImager.swift:131:9
3.  While silgen closureexpr SIL function @_TFFFE8BeamItUpPS_16ScrollViewImagerP33_22F49B169CD6FD663C230349D2C79AE615makeScreenshotsFT6pointsGSaGSaVSC7CGPoint__6framesGSaGSaVSC6CGRect__5scaleV12CoreGraphics7CGFloat10completionFT11screenshotsGSaGSaCSo7UIImage___T__T_L_21internalScreenshotRowFT_T_U_FGSaS5__T_ for expression at [/ScrollViewImager.swift:132:99 - line:135:13] RangeText="{ (screenshot) -> Void in
                counter += 1
                images.append(screenshot)
            }"
```

The ScrollViewImager is an open source library for taking screenshots of scrollview [Reference](https://github.com/romainmenke/ScrollViewImager)

Comment: i'll take a look at it

Comment: The quickest way to resolve this was to remove the Mixin Pattern and implement a regular `extension`. It works now. Sim might give funky screenshots, but works on device.

Comment: [source on github](https://github.com/romainmenke/ScrollViewImager)

Comment: @RMenke, can you please put this as an answer? I can then close this question...